# AngularJS example in $resource API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

In the above link, there is an example:

```
// Define CreditCard class
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
 {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
  charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
 });

// We can retrieve a collection from the server
var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
  // GET: /user/123/card
  // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];

  var card = cards[0];
  // each item is an instance of CreditCard
  expect(card instanceof CreditCard).toEqual(true);
  card.name = "J. Smith";
  // non GET methods are mapped onto the instances
  card.$save();
  // POST: /user/123/card/456 {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
  // server returns: {id:456, number:'1234', name: 'J. Smith'};

  // our custom method is mapped as well.
  card.$charge({amount:9.99});
  // POST: /user/123/card/456?amount=9.99&charge=true {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
});

// we can create an instance as well
var newCard = new CreditCard({number:'0123'});
newCard.name = "Mike Smith";
newCard.$save();
// POST: /user/123/card {number:'0123', name:'Mike Smith'}
// server returns: {id:789, number:'01234', name: 'Mike Smith'};
expect(newCard.id).toEqual(789);
```

there is a line:

```
var card = cards[0];
```

1. I have no idea where the array `cards` is coming from. The only match I found is at the previous line and it doesn't make sense to me as that is a variable outside of the function scope.
2. For the jasmine expect function, does Angular actually run it and throw an error?

There are lines with function `expect()`, such as:

```
expect(card instanceof CreditCard).toEqual(true);
```

I know this is a Jasmine testing function, but I wonder if the browser/Angular directly runs it as I don't see any Jasmine library in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question 1. The line your referring to (var card = cards[0];) is occurring inside the success callback of the *query* method. This means it has successfully executed, which in turn means that the *cards* variable will be populated. The *cards* variable is not outside of scope, it can be referenced inside the callback function, and any other function for that matter. Typically you would not use the *cards* variable outside the scope of the success callback, as it's an asynchronous method.

Please elaborate on question 2?

Comment: thanks, you are right, the function inside query() is actually a $http success functin